# How can i send my array to other component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to send my product array in the other "cart component" to display the products in the tables.
When I press the button, it is creating the array with the products and I don't know how to send the array of products for the other cart component.

ProductCart(component).
This is the component where I am creating my products array when i push the button "add to cart".

```
function ProductCard(props){

  const[items, setItems] = useState([])
  console.log(items);

  const addToCart = () =>{
    setItems([
      ...items, 
      {
        name: props.product.name,
        price: props.product.price
      }
      ]);
  };

    return(
      <div>
        <Card className="card-style" border="primary" style={{widht:'18rem', flex: 1}}>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.product.image} />
            <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{props.product.name}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>Price: ${props.product.price}, Quantity: {props.product.quantity}
                  </Card.Text>
                  <Button onClick={() => addToCart()}>Add to Cart</Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    
    )

   
}

export default ProductCard
```

Cart(component).
This is the component where i want to send my product array and show the added products in the tables.

```
    function Cart(){
        return(
                 <div>
            <Table striped border hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Products</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </Table>
        </div>
            
        )
    }


export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Cart items={items}/>
```

```
function Cart(props){
   // Use props.items
}
```

Comment: but the problem is in <Cart items = {items} /> because in the component of my products the tables is shown

Comment: describe in detail.

Comment: or maybe i set <Cart items = {items} /> in the place wrong. because is my first time using react so i set <Cart items = {items} /> in productscard, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

So If I understood correctly your problem, You want to access your "Items" in "Cart" component.

A better approach would be to use some state management component like Redux and set "Items" state there and access it from "Cart" component.

Have you tried by using Redux or some other component here? If yes, then what is the behavior? Are you getting any error?

Comment: i want to send my products to the cart, and answering your question i have never used redux, i´m just starting to develop in react and javascript.